# Ruby on Rails - fullcalendar linked with datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, fullcalendar

How to link fullcalendar with datepicker, so that it looks like on the picture below using Rails 5 and `gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'` + `gem 'fullcalendar-rails'`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've struggled through lots of posts on stackoverflow with partial answers, and eventually managed to link datepicker and fullcalendar using the below code in application.js:

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      format: "dd.mm.yyyy"
  })
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
      $('#event_calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', ev.date);
  });

function eventCalendar() {
  return $('#event_calendar').fullCalendar({ 
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    viewRender: function(view, element){
        var currentdate = view.intervalStart;
        $('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date(currentdate));
    }
    });
};
```

view.haml:

```
#event_calendar

#datepicker
```